# OAuth for Javascript Website (with Spring Server)

Tags: spring, angular, oauth

Im having a problem to understand the OAuth flow with Spring.

I have a server running, which got protected endpoints to deliver metric data about the users, revenue usw.

These are used inside an admin panel written in Angular2. Currently the access_token for these endpoints is received by sending the ClientId/Secret and username password to my server.

But obviously its bad to store the Clientsecret on a javascript site.

So I need a way to retreive an access_token from javascript without exposing the client_secret.

I tried to implement the Spring OAuth2 implicit flow which somehow works, but only when I type it inside a browser so the /login page from spring shows up.

My Admin panel has its own Login page so this doesnt work out.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: As here both client & server are your own, so you can use Resource Owner Password Credential flow. Try to create 2 Spring boot app, a client & server. Where client id and secret for given client should be store in your spring boot app's properties file or database whatever you want